# Numpy Arrays, wrong shape

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm taking an entry level ML course and I'm working on analysing the iris dataset from the sklearn library, and one thing I need to do is print out the third feature associated with the list of data. I also need to make sure that the shape is (150,).

What I tried:

`x = iris.data[:, 2:3]` Which does give me the third feature, but the shape is (150,1) rather than (150,) and I don't quite understand why.

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iris.data[:, 2:3]` gives you a view of features 2 (incl) to 3 (excl), think of that as a list of 1 feature, hence the last `1` in your shape. Just use `iris.data[:, 2]` directly to make it a 1 dimensional array (whose shape has length 1).

Comment: So `iris.data[:, view]` is a 2d array with one column being empty?

Comment: It's 2D, with one column being the one you want. Try printing `np.zeros(5)` and `np.zeros((5,1))` to see the difference...